# Why is the entire list re-rendered after updating one element in the entityAdapter selector from redux-toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a feed slice:

```
const feedSlice = createSlice({
name: 'feed',
initialState: {
    reposteds: repostedsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    comments: commentsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    authors: authorsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    groups: groupsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    posts: postsAdapter.getInitialState(),
    lastPostId: undefined,
    loading: true,
    error: false,
},
reducers: {
    postUpdate: (state, { payload }) => {
        postsAdapter.updateOne(state.posts, payload);
    },
},
});
```

And I create a selector for posts and other adapters from documentation about entityAdapter:

```
export const postsSelector = postsAdapter
.getSelectors(({ feed }) => feed.posts);
```

When I render a list of posts I get Ids selector for render list:

```
const postsIds = useSelector((state) => postsSelector.selectIds(state));
```

And in post component I get all needed data with selectors:

```
const post = useSelector((state) => postsSelector.selectById(state, postId));
const group = useSelector((state) => groupsSelector.selectById(state, post.groupId));
const author = useSelector((state) => authorsSelector.selectById(state, post.authorId));
const reposted = useSelector((state) => repostedsSelector.selectById(state, post.repostedId));
```

And after changing the post, by calling the action "updatePost" from the feedSlice code, the entire list of posts is rerendered. Why are my selectors not working, what am I doing wrong?